# configure proxy in erlang .config file

Tags: erlang

Usually I do configure the proxy using:

```
httpc:set_options([{proxy, {{"www-proxy.mycompany.com", 8000},
  ["localhost"]}}]).
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result using the config file?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can either use the config file (specified [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html)) or you can use any .hrl file.

The latter option is the one I use, as you can just

```
-include("settings.hrl").
```

in your file. The settings.hrl file might be looking like this

```
-define(PORT, 8080).
-define(URL, "http://my.url").
```

And in your code you can then use these defines as follows

```
httpc:set_options([{proxy, {{?URL, ?PORT}, ["localhost"]}}]).
```